# grouping repeating xml data with xsl

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I have an XML file that I need to transform with XSL to group tags with the same attribute-value name(@name). In the sample input below, the only repeating value is "objectClass". I can't seem to find any other posts that solve the problem that I'm having. Below is my input, code, current output and desired output. XSL 2.0 is not an option for me.

Input:

```
<top>
<MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    <DN>cn=BRK001,ou=USERS,ou=INTERNAL,o=UMB</DN>
    <attribute-value name="passwordUniqueRequired">TRUE</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="passwordRequired">TRUE</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="uid">BRK001</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="initials">R</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="cn">BRK001</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="umbGUID">I00000000001498</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">inetOrgPerson</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">umbPerson</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">organizationalPerson</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">Person</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">ndsLoginProperties</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">Top</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="umbCustomer">22586</attribute-value>
</MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
<MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    <DN>cn=BRK001,ou=USERS,ou=INTERNAL,o=UMB</DN>
    <attribute-value name="passwordUniqueRequired">TRUE</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="passwordRequired">TRUE</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="uid">BRK001</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="initials">R</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="cn">BRK001</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="umbGUID">I00000000001498</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">inetOrgPerson</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">umbPerson</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">organizationalPerson</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">Person</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">ndsLoginProperties</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="objectClass">Top</attribute-value>
    <attribute-value name="umbCustomer">22586</attribute-value>
</MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
</top>
```

Current XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="test" match="attribute-value" use="@name"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="ldapMapping">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$ldapMapping"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData']">
    <xsl:variable name="ldapFormatted">
    <MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
            <entries>
                <xsl:for-each select="attribute-value[count(. | key('test', @name)[1]) = 1]">
                    <attributes>
                        <name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                        </name>
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('test', @name)">
                            <value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </value>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </attributes>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </entries>
        </MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:copy-of select="$ldapFormatted"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Current Output:

```
<top>
<MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    <entries>
        <attributes>
            <name>passwordUniqueRequired</name>
            <value>TRUE</value>
            <value>TRUE</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>passwordRequired</name>
            <value>TRUE</value>
            <value>TRUE</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>uid</name>
            <value>BRK001</value>
            <value>BRK001</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>initials</name>
            <value>R</value>
            <value>R</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>cn</name>
            <value>BRK001</value>
            <value>BRK001</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>umbGUID</name>
            <value>I00000000001498</value>
            <value>I00000000001498</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>objectClass</name>
            <value>inetOrgPerson</value>
            <value>umbPerson</value>
            <value>organizationalPerson</value>
            <value>Person</value>
            <value>ndsLoginProperties</value>
            <value>Top</value>
            <value>inetOrgPerson</value>
            <value>umbPerson</value>
            <value>organizationalPerson</value>
            <value>Person</value>
            <value>ndsLoginProperties</value>
            <value>Top</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>umbCustomer</name>
            <value>22586</value>
            <value>22586</value>
        </attributes>
    </entries>
</MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
<MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    <entries/>
</MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
</top>
```

Desired Output:

```
<top>
<MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    <entries>
        <attributes>
            <name>passwordUniqueRequired</name>
            <value>TRUE</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>passwordRequired</name>
            <value>TRUE</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>uid</name>
            <value>BRK001</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>initials</name>
            <value>R</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>cn</name>
            <value>BRK001</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>umbGUID</name>
            <value>I00000000001498</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>objectClass</name>
            <value>inetOrgPerson</value>
            <value>umbPerson</value>
            <value>organizationalPerson</value>
            <value>Person</value>
            <value>ndsLoginProperties</value>
            <value>Top</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>umbCustomer</name>
            <value>22586</value>
        </attributes>
    </entries>
</MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
<MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
    <entries>
        <attributes>
            <name>passwordUniqueRequired</name>
            <value>TRUE</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>passwordRequired</name>
            <value>TRUE</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>uid</name>
            <value>BRK001</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>initials</name>
            <value>R</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>cn</name>
            <value>BRK001</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>umbGUID</name>
            <value>I00000000001498</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>objectClass</name>
            <value>inetOrgPerson</value>
            <value>umbPerson</value>
            <value>organizationalPerson</value>
            <value>Person</value>
            <value>ndsLoginProperties</value>
            <value>Top</value>
        </attributes>
        <attributes>
            <name>umbCustomer</name>
            <value>22586</value>
        </attributes>
    </entries>
</MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData>
</top>
```

If I only have one MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData grouping, the tags are grouped correctly but when I have multiple iterations, which I will, it groups them together as shown above which I don't want. I understand why it's doing it but can't figure out how to keep the grouping within the MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="attr" match="attribute-value" use="concat(@name, '|', generate-id(..))"/>

<xsl:template match="/top">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="MPTPartyUserInqMultiLDAPData">
    <xsl:copy>
        <entries>
            <xsl:for-each select="attribute-value[count(. | key('attr', concat(@name, '|', generate-id(..)))[1])=1]">
                <attributes>
                    <name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </name>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('attr', concat(@name, '|', generate-id(..)))">
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </value>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </attributes>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </entries>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Initial testing shows that it works(xmlSpy). I'll add my "real life" testing results when I'm done(DataPower service).

Comment: Thanks again, Michael. I had to tweak it a bit because my actual input XML was a SOAP message and there was other data in the file that needed to be included in the resulting file. I was able to make that change quickly. I have to say that I wouldn't have come up with what you posted in a hundred years. Consider this thread answered.